# R: error in dimnames when using colnames with matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Imagine the case to preallocate a 2x2 matrix with NAs. Now I would like to rename the first column to "Test" with

```
name_matrix<-matrix(NA,2,2)
colnames(name_matrix)[1] <- "Test"
```

But now I am getting the error message:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Whereas if I convert the matrix to a data.frame first I am not ending up with this error message.

```
name_data_frame<-as.data.frame(name_matrix)
colnames(name_data_frame)[1] <- "Test"
```

My question is does anybody have an idea how to find out more about this unexpected behavior and maybe as well how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after the first line

```
name_matrix<-matrix(NA,2,2)
```

the value of `colnames(name_matrix)` is `NULL` for which it does not make sense to access its first entry `colnames(name_matrix)[1]`.
Instead you have to assign the entire variable a vector of length 2.
For instance you could do:

```
colnames(name_matrix)<- c("Test", NA)
```